# How to test the performance of thrift service by loadRunner?

Tags: performance, testing, soa, thrift, performance-testing

I build a service used thrift, and host it on a tomcat server by TServlet , the protocol is TCompactProtocol

I want to test the service by loadrunner, but i don't know how to record the test script

Comment: Hi @AlanShen; welcome to StackOverflow. You need to better qualify your question better: performance in terms of what?  (Requests per second?  Throughput?  Server resources consumed?  Hairs pulled out due to maintanance issues?)

Answer (score 0):

What protocol you would select for your thrift interface testing is entirely dependent upon the transport used in your implementation

http://thrift.apache.org/docs/concepts/

If raw TCP, then Winsock.   If HTTP, then Web Virtual User (with Web_custom_requests() and recording headers), etc....

Note, not all interfaces are recordable.   Some you will have to build code directly.   With Thirft you ~~may~~ be able to build a client using the Java template virtual user type.

If this is your first venture into sockets of Java virtual user types then you will want to have a mentor with you for the ride.  Otherwise its going to be extremely painful and far less fruitful than it should be.